# Azure Mobile Service Casting JSON to Type in VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, linq, azure

Hi there I have been messing with Azure Mobile Services recently and after solving one problem I have come up against another one. I have a stored procedure held on my Azure SQL db which is then invoked by a custom API on my Mobile service.

In my client I can call the API to return a JSON token (or array):

```
Dim result As Linq.JToken = Await App.subtlesoftClient.InvokeApiAsync("test1", 
              System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, Nothing)
```

I then convert this into a json string:

```
Dim jString As String = result.ToString
```

Which gives me:

```
{[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "message": "This is another test message cos everything is almost almost great but what can you do eh",
    "messageDate": "2015-05-10T00:00:00Z"
  }
]}
```

What I can't figure out is how to take the result and pass it into my class:

```
Public Class test1

    Private _ID As Integer
    Private _MessageDate As Date
    Private _Message As String

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="id")>
    Public Property ID As Integer
        Get
            Return _ID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _ID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="message")>
    Public Property Message As String
        Get
            Return _Message
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Message = value
        End Set
    End Property
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="messageDate")>
    Public Property MessageDate As Date
        Get
            Return _MessageDate
        End Get
        Set(value As Date)
            _MessageDate = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I have tried:

```
Dim myArray = result.Children(Of Linq.JProperty)().
            FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = "").Value
```

To try and put it into an array I can enumerate through. This causes errors probably because I am not passing a name into the function as my json does not appear to have a name.

Ultimately the return json will be multiple objects so I want to be able to pass them into a `MobileServiceCollection(Of MyType)`, and I don't know how. The documentation on this seems pretty scant.

Comment: If that was valid json you could deserialize directly to your class.  As is, the `[ ]` pair and inner `{ }` set wrap nothing and everything is objecting to it.  If/when there are more than one object, the result might be a `List(of myClassName)`

Comment: Hi yes the visualizer complains there is something wrong with the object, but as soon as I convert it too a string the visualizer works fine.

Comment: json strings are serialized data.  you dont cast them to something else, they are deserialized to objects. *directly* to objects as opposed to "passing" them to a class.  when fixed, `Dim myMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Msg)(jstr)` works as expected

Comment: OK thanks for that. When I convert that to work for my text I get an exception of, "Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Ponda.test1' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly." Which goes back to what you mentioned before that my json object is malformed, which begs the question why.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks for giving me some pointers anyway seems it was very easy in the end, isn't it always when you figure it out:

`Dim result = Await App.subtlesoftClient.InvokeApiAsync("test1", System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, Nothing)`

```
            Dim jString As String = result.ToString

            Dim myTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of test1))(jString)
```

This works fine, seems the square brackets on the JSON string indicate its is an array.